# What is the difference among 'dormitorio', 'recámara', 'alcoba' and 'habitación'?

Tags: diferencias-regionales, diferencias-entre-palabras

What are the differences among these words?

- dormitorio
- recámara
- alcoba
- habitación

The dictionary says they all mean "bedroom"; I suspect it's a regional/dialectical thing.

What are these words used for in your country/region and which of these is the most common one for "bedroom" in your country?

Please do mention your country so I know which dialect we are talking about.

Comment: it's missing `cuarto` in Cuba we use more often habitación and cuarto, all those words have the same meaning. they are synonymous.

Comment: missing *covacha*.

Comment: I don't understand why you say `dialect of Spanish by nationality` all countries that have Spanish as official language, speak Spanish or `Castellano` how it's properly called, each country has their own idioms, but it's the same language. link to [Dialecto](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dialecto#Criterios_utilizados_para_distinguir_los_dialectos)

Comment: @c.p. **Covacha**? Never heard of that word? Where is it used?

Comment: I'm sorry. It's meaning is *cave*, but don't use it. It's somehow derogatory for *little room*, but no body uses it. I added it just for fun.

Comment: Interesting! I grew up (Mexican relatives) hearing recamara, Rosetta Stone Latin American Spanish doesn't even mention that word, they use dormitorio or habitacion.

Comment: Actually none. Just different regions has different ways of saying the same thing.

Comment: @TheLearner  You might find this useful:

[**covacha**](https://tureng.com/en/spanish-english/covacha)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In Mexico... all 4 words are used for bedroom:

**Recámara** also means chamber (the part of a pistol)

**Alcoba** as @rodrigo says, is only used in books, novels and so on, although in some places (like hotels) you can find **alcoba matrimonial**  referring to a wedding suite.

**Dormitorio** could be "dorm", a place when you find lots of beds

**Habitación** could be any room, just a place surrounded by 4 walls

**Cuarto** also means bedroom but has other meanings like "the fourth part of something" (Un cuarto the kilo - 1/4 kilo)

Comment: Alcoba sounds *'mamón'* ;). In typical translation English to Spanish of series: "ve a tu alcoba" sounds just horrible. And so does *rosquilla* for donought and *dentífrico* for *pasta de dientes*. I cannot stand it. (+1 btw.)

Comment: @c.p. si alguien que no fuera dentista me dijera `dentífrico ` por `pasta de dintes` lo daría por loco

Comment: @EmilioGort :D ... yo me cuidaría pues eso significaría que no estudió odontología, sino para traductor de series.

Comment: I'm from @Argentina, and agree with this. But I wouldn't say any room could be an "habitación", just those that are part of a residential building (house, hotel, etc.). In a business it sounds odd for me to name "habitación" to any room.

Answer (score 10):

I'm from Northern Spain.

Here the most common word is **habitación**:

> ¡Vete a tu habitación!
> <sub>Go to your bedroom!</sub>

However, in books and on TV, **cuarto** is probably more often seen and heard:

> ¡Vete a tu cuarto!

Both are used with a possesive, thus **tu habitación** and **tu cuarto** means **your bedroom** or **your room**.

But without the possesive, they may refer to any room, so in these cases **dormitorio** is used:

> Se vende una casa con 4 dormitorios.
> <sub>House sold with 4 bedrooms.</sub>

**alcoba** sounds archaic. It can be used for rhetoric, poetic turns of phrase, or humoristic effect, except when it refers metaphorically to a marriage (or some similar relationship status in which a bed is shared), particularly in the idiom:

> Problemas de alcoba.
> <sub>Marriage issues.</sub>

**recámara** is almost never used.

Comment: Cuando voy al cuarto de baño no uso ningún posesivo.

Comment: @Jdamian Eso mismo indica la respuesta en "But without the possesive, they may refer to any room"

Answer (score 4):

Here in Chile we say *pieza* or *dormitorio*. Almost never *habitación*, and never, never *alcoba*, *cuarto* or *recámara*.

Answer (score 1):

They may all have exactly the same meaning, they do not all have the same context.

`Cuarto` - Quarters.  Living quarters.  It's a very ancient term in English, but it still lingers in the spanish language.

`Recámara`, to me, makes me think of a hotel room, or a room for rent.

`Alcoba`, I have never heard, but judging from the others' attempt to translate it, I find it to mean nothing more than a `room`.  Not a bedroom in particular, but rather just a room.

`Aula` is something I know has classroom.

`Habituación` sounds like a very proper, fancy way to refer to a bedroom; I can see why it would be used in Spain.

`Dormitorio` is exactly what you would think it is, a dormitory.  In English, the word `dormitory` or `domicile` are very proper names for a bedroom.

So again, even though they all mean the same thing, they deserve their contexts.

Answer (score 0):

I'm from Argentina and we say ***pieza*** to mean "bedroom".